# Does Neo4J support map/reduce jobs?

Tags: mapreduce, neo4j

Neo4j supports master/slave distribution mechanism in distributed systems. Does Neo4J support map/reduce jobs for querying in distributed system?

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I was working on map-reduce jobs for MongoDB, CouchDB and some other databases.  So, I am wondering if is there any direct support in Neo4j's API for that?

Comment: What do you want to do.

Comment: nothing....just curious to know....:)

Comment: Ah, ok, then what Rolf said, but you can also do it in code (we could abstract that out though), see: https://github.com/maxdemarzi/graph_processing/blob/2.3/src/main/java/com/maxdemarzi/processing/PageRankArrayStorageParallelSPI.java which computes page-rank on dbpedia in 90 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really Map/Reduce, but you can distribute some graph algorithms with [Mazerunner](https://github.com/kbastani/neo4j-mazerunner), built on top of [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/), [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/graphx/) and (extended) Neo4j instances.